# How to set datatype in SQLiteDatabase raw query binding?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, casting

Arguments in SQLiteDatabase [raw query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) function are bound as **Strings** and it causes problems for me.

Example query (binding **50**):

```
    SELECT ? < 68
```

returns: `0`

```
    SELECT min(?, 68)
```

returns: `68`

Such results are because `50` is bound as String and query looks like `SELECT '50' < 68 ;` which returns `false`.

Having complicated query created at runtime I have to use `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery`.

How to bind data as **Integer**?

I found one solution:

```
SELECT CAST( ? AS INTEGER ) < 68 ;
```

but it looks ugly. Is there any other way? I can't find any adequate methods in Android API.

Comment: The javadoc of `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql, args)` claims "only byte[], String, Long and Double are supported in bindArgs". Does it help to use a `Long` instead of an `Integer`? Some code reduce the guessing, too :)

Comment: Javadoc for `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql, args)` says: `Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`. I need SELECT. But the problem is in using any different types than `String` not only Integer or Long.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are right -- it says so in the first sentence in all caps :(

Comment: No problem :). As you pointed out, execSQL supports different types, but rawQuery not. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question now, but you should use compileStatement followed by [bindLong](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html#bindLong%28int,%20long%29) on the resulting SQLiteProgram class. This is Google's way of giving people smart enough to use SQL the extra push to compile statements for better performance.

Comment: I'll take a look but it seems to be difficult or even impossible to use with very complicated queries.